# How can I accept Monero payments from my classifieds ads website with unique client information

Tags: payment-id, payment-integration

Can someone suggest a solution for me please? I am in the UK.

I will be creating a classifieds website and I am looking for a way to accept Monero payments from my advertisers.  I am not a coder, but I can create a simple website using the Wordpress plugins.  I don’t have a computing background. I will be running my website from my PC, so I would prefer solutions which do not involve mobile phones. However, I do like what Monerujo has to offer and if there is no other way, I will get a smartphone with android to run it and use it.  I would prefer a solution that does not involve third party payment processors.

I’m aware of Woocommerce though I have never used it.  I have a Trezor hard wallet which doesn’t have Monero capability, but I will buy a Nano wallet which does offer Monero integration if need be.  I have not used crypto-currencies and know nothing to little. So I’d like a solution which is simple to use on  a PC with Windows 10 64bits  I am wondering if I can make it for what I want to do which I will now describe.

I would like users on my website to be able to pay with Monero. My website will have mainly free adverts, but some categories and locations will incur a charge. Let us say, £5 for a week for the UK site, or the equivalent in foreign currencies. My site will be global and I want to give customers the option to pay in Monero.

How could I accept Monero from my customers direct from my website? Customers will be paying weekly amounts for placing classified ads. Depending on the currency fluctuation, I am assuming the rates will change daily so customers would need to pay the correct amount.  The payments should be automated as they will be coming from different countries. I would need to know who is sending what. Each transaction should have some kind of unique reference which no other customer will have. I would prefer not to use payment providers like Coinbase, I'd prefer payments direct.

What software, wallet, and payment conversion could do all the above? After each sale I’d like to receive an email sent to me, telling me who paid what for which classifieds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a coder and want to allow people to pay in Monero, maybe the easiest way is to consider https://globee.com, a payment processor which allows people to pay with Monero, while settling in your choice of Monero, Bitcoin or fiat (maybe not yours though, do check).